# Raphael JS: how to use jQuery selectors on objects in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, raphael, vml

I'm trying to use Raphael JS, but jQuery selectors don't seem to work with Raphael JS in IE8.

In Chrome and Firefox this works:

```
  var paper = ScaleRaphael("test", 500, 500);

  var c = paper.circle(50, 50, 40);

  c.node.setAttribute('class','bluecircle');

  $('.bluecircle').attr({fill: 'blue'});
```

But in Internet Explorer (IE8, which uses VML instead of SVG)  nothing is shown.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to give each object a class, so I can use Jquery selectors to manipulate all objects at once that have a certain class...

Does anybody know a way how to do this, that also works in IE ?

Comment: I'm working on this problem too, but only very recently, and I haven't gotten any further than you. The underlying question: does IE expose any method to get VML objects by class name?

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly the same as using classes to address a group of objects, but I wrote a [patch against Raphael](https://github.com/ecenter/raphael/commit/b16106e5f2107e00566ca02c6bb5b89682994b13) to allow for named sets. Simply invoke with `paper.set('uniqueID', element1, element2, ...)`. Elements contain a groups array with each group they've been assigned to, and the top Raphael paper object has a groups dictionary keyed by the 'uniqueID'.

The following test code shows how you can apply a hover handler to a named set, and use the hover callback to turn all the members of the group black on hover:

```
var marker1 = paper.circle(50, 20, 10).attr({'fill' : '#ff0000'});
var marker2 = paper.circle(100, 20, 10).attr({'fill' : '#ff0000'});
var marker3 = paper.circle(150, 20, 10).attr({'fill' : '#ff0000'});
var marker4 = paper.circle(200, 20, 10).attr({'fill' : '#ff0000'});

var s = paper.set('setID', marker1, marker2);
s.push(marker3, marker4);
s.pop();

// If marker 1, 2, or 3 is hovered, act on whole group
s.hover(function() {
  for (var i = 0, ii = this.groups.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var set = this.paper.groups[this.groups[i]];
    for (var j = 0, jj = set.items.length; j < jj; ++j) {
      set.items[j].attr({'fill' : '#000000'});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I've not checked if the implementation of sets has changed in V2.0. So will this still work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
c.node.className = 'bluecircle';
```

Comment: Nope. There are other threads that suggest it and my preliminary tests indicate these people are just wrong :(