# Raphael JS Event Bubbling

Tags: javascript, event-handling, raphael

Is there any way to simulate event bubbling in Raphael JS? I have several circular objects that I'd like to put icons in, but all of my event handling (hover, click, drag) on the circles gets messed up once I put the icons on top (the icons capture the hover, click, drag events instead).

I've considered several options, but most of them are very, very messy (cross calling all sort of event handlers in an attempt to "sync" the icon and the button) when all I really want to do is "group" the icon and circle together as one button. An easier way out would be to make the circle + button an image itself but I'd like to be able to dynamically change the color of the buttons so it'd be a hassle to change the colors of the images manually.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and the `set` object doesn't handle event bubbling either. Hope to hear a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making a large transparent shape that is higher in the z-order and covers the desired area?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you still can't 'sync' the underlying items without additional techniques.

Comment: I have tried this approach too, Raphael events get fired, but because the paper overlays the html elements, the underlying elements do not get an event.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this and have a patch against Raphael that allows named sets: See my answer at [Raphael JS: how to use jQuery selectors on objects in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277129/raphael-js-how-to-use-jquery-selectors-on-objects-in-ie/6944372#6944372)

By inspecting an element's set membership in your hover function, you can easily manipulate other elements of the set at the same time. This isn't true event bubbling, but it accomplishes the same goal in a cross-browser compatible way.