# Querying class on Raphael object

Tags: class, raphael

I have this array of rects using jQuery and Raphael:

```
squares = [];
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    var square = paper.rect(0 + 100*i, 0, 70, 70);
    square.node.idx = i;
    square.node.setAttribute('class', 'foo');
    squares.push(square);
}
```

I can successfully query various attributes, like:

```
alert(squares[0].attr('x'));
```

or

```
alert(squares[0].attr('width'));
```

but **not**:

```
alert(squares[0].attr('class'));
```

Is there a special reason for which this is not valid?
Is there an (other) way to query the class attribute?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in SVG [aren't quite the same](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/c2c56e4591f4f101) as classes in everything else - and in Raphael, which deals with SVG and IE's VML, things get even more hairy.

First of all, they're on the page's DOM element (Raphael's output) not in the Raphael JS object itself. You'd use Raphael's `.node` to get the actual DOM path (e.g. with jQuery, `$(squares[0].node).someJqueryFunction();`) but this sort of thing is best avoided where possible for the above reasons. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522967/how-to-add-a-css-class-to-a-raphael-object) has answers with more info.

If you want to use classes to store data (e.g. like using 'active', 'inactive' classes as switches), you're best off using Raphael's [`.data` function](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data) which [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830330/delegating-drag-function-in-raphael#answer-8830777) is for storing arbitrary values. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627105/raphael-js-custom-attributes) has answers with more info.

Comment: (just edited this to not advise bad practice of adding arbitrary data to the Raphael object directly, and instead, to use the .data function which I hear is designed for this)