# How to select a raphael svg tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I'm quite new to Raphael, and quite lost too in its documentation...

I'd like to manipulate a Raphael object through jQuery:

```
$(".handle").hover(
               function() {
                     $("path[rel='"+$(this).attr('rel')+"']").addClass("pathhover");
               }, 
               function() {
                    $("path").removeClass("pathhover");
               }
            );
```

Path is a Raphael-generated path, and jQuery does not seem to be able to select this svg tag.

Would you have an idea how to achieve this ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Try path.node.removeClass("pathhover")

Comment: Thanks, but if path is the Raphael object, I don't know which one to call. That's the reason why I use the rel tag to select the right one...

Comment: Have a look at this Q and A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187856/jquery-raphael-svg-selector-based-on-custom-data

Comment: Thanks ; I better understand the cause of the problem.
However, I still don't really understand how to select the object from the rel value of its node...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, thanks to jacktheripper help.

The raphael object can't be manipulated directly by jQuery; we need to use its reference to the DOM (its [node](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.node)).

Therefore, the jQuery handler needs the Raphael object name. In this example, I use the rel tag to store the name of the raphael object.

```
$(".handle").hover(
               function() {
                     var path=eval($(this).attr('rel'));
                     path.node.setAttribute("class","pathhover");
               }, 
               function() {
                    var path=eval($(this).attr('rel'));
                    path.node.removeAttribute("class","pathhover");
               }
            );
```