# get SVG element as a Raphael Object

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I create SVG using Raphael library in my project. I set id to SVG. 
The problem is; I didn't find the way to get SVG object as a raphael paper by Id. when I get the SVG using jQuery like that `$(filterId) or $(filterId)[0]` , It returns `SVGSVGElement` Object so I can not use Raphael's functions.

```
Raphael("filterDiv", 1100, 1000);
$("svg:last").attr("id","filterId");
```

Thanks

Comment: This might answer your query http://stackoverflow.com/a/12340244/94278

Answer (score 0):

The SVG element and the Raphael object are not the same thing. It's a good idea to store the Raphael object when you create it, e.g. `paper=Raphael("filterDiv", 1100, 1000);`.